# Delete all the array items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I delete all the items from a JavaScript array?

example -

```
var myArray1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// I want it to become this
myArray = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function clearArray(array) {
  while (array.length) {
    array.pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

But can I do something like this - 

```
array.length = 0;
 ```